# fill a hollow shape with color

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

say i have drawn a circle or any shape which has a boundary and within it a hollow space in html canvas.i want to fill it with a selected color.what  algorithm can do the job for me.i have added a picture of a hollow shape and i want to fill the white space within the black boundary.how this can be done using javascript.how mouse events lyk

```
e.layerX/Y ;e.ClientX/Y
```

can be used

[image: here is my drawing shape.i want to fill the space within it with color]

Comment: This nice demo by William Malone will show you how to floodfill a closed shape with a color:  http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-javascript-paint-bucket-tool/

Comment: it seems like a great site.thanks! :)

Comment: If you're interested, in this fiddle there's Malone's version, and one i did myself which is way faster. http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/gTa4r/

Comment: thanks!but i don't know what happened, when redraw button is clicked firefox  crashes every time..

Comment: I just tested on latest Ch/FF/Sf (mac OS), and it works... ???

Comment: @GameAlchemist: your code glitch likely results from `imgData.data` still being a `CanvasPixelArray` in some browsers rather than a  `Uint8ClampedArray`.  This difference is exposed when you try to init your buffer32 with `imgData.data.buffer` ;-)

Comment: @markE : most interesting, thanks. Annoying thing that some browsers (none on macOS, it seems), do not comply with current standards. How could i fix this ? a quick fix would be to copy the CvPxArr in a new ‘Uint8ClampedArray‘ ... with quite a cost... Other solution i see is painfull  : write special version for CanvasPixelArray.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Stack-based_recursive_implementation_.28Four-way.29) to fill the region. It takes a starting point (or the **seed point**) as an input and recursively fills the region, by attempting to fill its neighbors.

You could get the seed point on a mouse click event, and then pass it to flood fill.
Here's a stack based code in JavaScript:

```
// Takes the seed point as input
var floodfill = function(point) {
    var stack = Array();
    stack.push(point); // Push the seed
    while(stack.length > 0) {
        var currPt = stack.pop();
        if(isEmpty(currPt.x, currPt.y)) { // Check if the point is not filled
            setPixel(currPt.x, currPt.y); // Fill the point
            stack.push(currPt.x + 1, currPt.y); // Fill the east neighbour
            stack.push(currPt.x, currPt.y + 1); // Fill the south neighbour
            stack.push(currPt.x - 1, currPt.y); // Fill the west neighbour
            stack.push(currPt.x, currPt.y - 1); // Fill the north neighbour
        }
    }
};
```

`isEmpty(x, y)` is the function that tests whether the point `(x, y)` is empty.

`setPixel(x, y)` fills the point `(x, y)`.

The implementation of these functions is left to you.

Note that the above algorithm used 4-neighborhood. But it can easily be extended to an 8-neighborhood.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo based on William Malone's tutorial:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/67xaB/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    //  The floodFill algorithm below is based on the good work by William Malone, Copyright 2010 William Malone (www.williammalone.com) -- Apache License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 -- Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
    var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
    var strokeColor =  {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0};
    var fillColor =  {r: 101,g: 155,b: 65};
    var fillData;
    var strokeData;


    // load image
    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        start();
    }
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/polygrid.png";


    function matchstrokeColor(r, g, b, a) {
      // never recolor the initial black divider strokes
      // must check for near black because of anti-aliasing
      return (r + g + b < 100 && a === 255);  
    }

    function matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB) {

      // get the color to be matched
      var r = strokeData.data[pixelPos],
        g = strokeData.data[pixelPos + 1],
        b = strokeData.data[pixelPos + 2],
        a = strokeData.data[pixelPos + 3];

      // If current pixel of the outline image is black-ish
      if (matchstrokeColor(r, g, b, a)) {
        return false;
      }

      // get the potential replacement color
      r = fillData.data[pixelPos];
      g = fillData.data[pixelPos + 1];
      b = fillData.data[pixelPos + 2];

      // If the current pixel matches the clicked color
      if (r === startR && g === startG && b === startB) {
        return true;
      }

      // If current pixel matches the new color
      if (r === fillColor.r && g === fillColor.g && b === fillColor.b) {
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    }

    // Thank you William Malone!
    function floodFill(startX, startY, startR, startG, startB) {
      var newPos;
      var x;
      var y;
      var   pixelPos;
      var   neighborLeft;
      var   neighborRight;
      var   pixelStack = [[startX, startY]];

      while (pixelStack.length) {

        newPos = pixelStack.pop();
        x = newPos[0];
        y = newPos[1];

        // Get current pixel position
        pixelPos = (y * canvasWidth + x) * 4;

        // Go up as long as the color matches and are inside the canvas
        while (y >= 0 && matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB)) {
          y -= 1;
          pixelPos -= canvasWidth * 4;
        }

        pixelPos += canvasWidth * 4;
        y += 1;
        neighborLeft = false;
        neighborRight = false;

        // Go down as long as the color matches and in inside the canvas
        while (y <= (canvasHeight-1) && matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB)) {
          y += 1;

          fillData.data[pixelPos]     = fillColor.r;
          fillData.data[pixelPos + 1] = fillColor.g;
          fillData.data[pixelPos + 2] = fillColor.b;
          fillData.data[pixelPos + 3] = 255;


          if (x > 0) {
            if (matchStartColor(pixelPos - 4, startR, startG, startB)) {
              if (!neighborLeft) {
                // Add pixel to stack
                pixelStack.push([x - 1, y]);
                neighborLeft = true;
              }
            } else if (neighborLeft) {
              neighborLeft = false;
            }
          }

          if (x < (canvasWidth-1)) {
            if (matchStartColor(pixelPos + 4, startR, startG, startB)) {
              if (!neighborRight) {
                // Add pixel to stack
                pixelStack.push([x + 1, y]);
                neighborRight = true;
              }
            } else if (neighborRight) {
              neighborRight = false;
            }
          }

          pixelPos += canvasWidth * 4;
        }
      }
    }

    // Start a floodfill
    // 1. Get the color under the mouseclick
    // 2. Replace all of that color with the new color
    // 3. But respect bounding areas! Replace only contiguous color.
    function paintAt(startX, startY) {

      // get the clicked pixel's [r,g,b,a] color data
      var pixelPos = (startY * canvasWidth + startX) * 4,
        r = fillData.data[pixelPos],
        g = fillData.data[pixelPos + 1],
        b = fillData.data[pixelPos + 2],
        a = fillData.data[pixelPos + 3];

      // this pixel's already filled
      if (r === fillColor.r && g === fillColor.g && b === fillColor.b) {
        return;
      }

      // this pixel is part of the original black image--don't fill
      if (matchstrokeColor(r, g, b, a)) {
        return;
      }

      // execute the floodfill
      floodFill(startX, startY, r, g, b);

      // put the colorized data back on the canvas
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
      context.putImageData(fillData, 0, 0);
      context.drawImage(img,0,0);
    }

    // create a random color object {red,green,blue}
    function randomColorRGB(){
        var hex=Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        var r=parseInt(hex.substring(0,2),16);
        var g=parseInt(hex.substring(2,4),16);
        var b=parseInt(hex.substring(4,6),16);
        return({r:r,g:g,b:b});    
    }

    // draw the image to the canvas and get its pixel array
    // listen for mouse clicks and do floodfill when clicked
    function start() {

      context.drawImage(img,0,0);
      strokeData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      fillData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
      context.drawImage(img,0,0);

      $('#canvas').mousedown(function (e) {
        // Mouse down location
        var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        var mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
        // set a new random fillColor
        fillColor=randomColorRGB();
        // floodfill
        paintAt(mouseX, mouseY);
      });

    };



}); // end $(function(){});

</script>

  </head>
  <body>
        <p>Click inside a shape below</p>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=210 height=300></canvas><br/>
  </body>
</html>
```